# Is a microcontroller's lifespan affected by voltage or clock?

Tags: microcontroller

Imagine we have two bunches of the same, regular microcontrollers called `myMCU` with maximum 2.5~5V supply and 40MHz system clock:

- 100000x `myMCU`s working at 3.0V with a clock of 20MHz
- 100000x of the same `myMCU`s working at 5.0V with a clock of 40MHz

Other parameters are the same for both cases including all naturally happening incidents from ice-ages to thunderstorms.

Which bunch of MCUs has a "higher chance" to last longer? By longer, I mean no limits; let's say after 400 years or so (which is the average lifespan of Greenland shark and reasonable to consider.)

**Notes:**

- This question may seem a little odd but I want to know aside from normal practices, do supply voltage and clock affect the lifespan of an IC regardless of the production?
- The microcontroller and all it's internal peripherals (GPIO, I2C, ADC, etc.) should be working to consider it OK.

Comment: Both voltages are probably regulated down to a common logic voltage for the actual CPU (typically around 1.2-1.8v), so I would not expect voltage you supply to make much, if any, difference on a typical MCU. If you actually could increase the logic (not supply) voltage you'd find that higher voltages eventually damage the CPU.

Comment: There is no way to answer this because there is no generic answer. The MCUs will last as long as the vendor guarantees that they will last. You have to request this data from the vendor. Usually flash data retention is the main concern and it's not really related to supply voltage nor system clock.

Comment: @Lundin This question is more theoretic than practical. So if the vendor says 40yrs lifespan, after 40 yrs, which group of above MCUs has a higher chance to contain more intact MCUs?

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad Not really theoretical. There are industry standard values MTTF (minimum time to failure) and B10 which is the time or number of operations until 10% of the parts can be expected to fail. The vendor should be able to give you these values.

Comment: And then there's also the life time of the solder joints keeping the MCU in place... if those aren't taken in account, all other calculations have no relevance.

Comment: What does "maximum 2.5~5V supply" mean?

Comment: @BruceAbbott it's just for the sake of question so we can compare a microcontroller at both 3.0V and 5.0V.

Answer (score 5):

Temperature is the strongest predictor of life under static conditions, so if the 5V one runs at a significantly higher die temperature you might expect it to fail first. The estimate of life halving for every 10°C is probably within reason.

If you want something like that to last a long time you run it cool and draw almost no current from any I/Os to prevent failures due to high current densities on tiny conductors.

And you avoid **thermal cycling** that can cause other kinds of failures. It doesn't matter if your 400 ball BGA chip will last 50 years if the solder joints fracture in 5 years.

And you run the  part conservatively well within specifications so any moderate shift in characteristics will not cause a failure. For example if the part is rated to operate at 40MHz maximum and you run it at 40MHz exactly there is no additional margin over whatever the manufacturer has included (particularly if it has to operate over a range of voltages and temperatures). However, if the part is only specified as capable of operating at 20MHz at 3V but is rated to operate at up to 50MHz at 5V there is more margin in the latter (when operated at 40MHz).

Comment: If precise timings are part of what the OP considers as "working", the same is true for the clock source device, if that is an external part.

Answer (score 3):

The 5V and 40MHz will have a lesser life time in general because

1. It will have more current consumption because of higher voltage and higher frequency. This means power dissipated in the chip is also higher & the junction temperature will be higher. So, electromigration of the internal routings will be higher for both these reasons.
2. At higher voltage and higher temp all reliability issues get exacerbated like gate-oxide integrity, HCI, etc.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments by Lundin against the question.

Now for some possible cases:

1. If the MCU core runs from a regulated voltage (internal to the MCU) then there will be little difference.
2. If the MCU does not run from a regulated internally generated voltage, then in very rough terms one can expect the higher voltage part to have a shorter lifetime.

The frequency will have little effect in all cases - provided the MCU is run at a frequency within its manufacturer ratings (which basically allows things like charge transfer / internal capacitances to be charged, switches to settle, states to be stable, yada yada).

Why voltage effect?  Mainly heating, and this in any modern process is going to be a pretty small effect.

Things that have a general effect on micro-electronic lifetime, in no special order:

- heat
- large current flows (metal migration)
- ingress of moisture
- shock, vibration
- general electrical stress (usually though this is more specifically heat or current)

Soldering, and the thermal effects of leads bonded to a PCB are of course an issues also but that's on the outside of the packaged microelectronic part.

Those things above are often not commonly taken into account in many designs:

Temperature degradation is a real effect.

Metal migration is real, and causes lifetime reduction but usually only where current density is high. Think high currents in MOSFETs, or transistors.

Moisture ingress is very real problem, although a combination of better packaging technology and things like IC passivation help a lot, compared to back in the 1970's and 1980's.

In terms of a real, noticeable, measurable difference in  the original question - there's unlikely to be anything statistically significant. Just a tendency. If doing a conservative design, run lower voltage and slower.